# Drag both circles and corresponding reactive text labels

Tags: d3.js

I need to make a scatter chart with draggable points and draggable text labels that react to their new positions, so far I have been able to plot the points and their respective labels but not make both their positions and the text labels reactive.

I tried attaching the drag class to the class that stores the text but to no avail. What am i missing out? Any help is appreciated.

https://jsfiddle.net/pdf8wn2h/

```
<script>

  var svg = d3.select("svg"),
      margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
      width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
      height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom;


  let points = [[0, 0], [1, 7],[2, 21],[3, 36],[4, 50],[5, 55],[6, 60],[7, 65],[8, 70],[9, 75],[10, 80],[11, 85],[12, 90],[13, 95],[14, 100],[15, 100]];

  var x = d3.scaleLinear()
  .rangeRound([0, width]);

  var y = d3.scaleLinear()
  .rangeRound([height, 0]);

  var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x),
      yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y);

  var line = d3.line()
  .x(function(d) { return x(d[0]); })
  .y(function(d) { return y(d[1]); });

  let drag = d3.drag()
  .on('start', dragstarted)
  .on('drag', dragged)
  .on('end', dragended);

  svg.append('rect')
    .attr('class', 'zoom')
    .attr('cursor', 'move')
    .attr('fill', 'none')
    .attr('pointer-events', 'all')
    .attr('width', width)
    .attr('height', height)
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')')

  var focus = svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

  x.domain(d3.extent(points, function(d) { return d[0]; }));
  y.domain(d3.extent(points, function(d) { return d[1]; }));

  focus.append("path")
    .datum(points)
    .attr("fill", "none")
    .attr("stroke", "green")
    .attr("stroke-linejoin", "round")
    .attr("stroke-linecap", "round")
    .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
    .attr("d", line);

  focus.selectAll('g')
    .data(points)
    .enter()
    .append('circle')
    .attr('r', 5.0)
    .attr('cx', function(d) { return x(d[0]);  })
    .attr('cy', function(d) { return y(d[1]); })
    .style('cursor', 'pointer')
    .style('fill', 'green');


  focus.selectAll('.dodo')
    .data(points)
    .enter()
    .append("text")
    .attr("class", "dodo")
    .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d[0]); })
    .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d[1]); })
    .attr("dx", ".71em")
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .text(function(d) { return d[1];});

  focus.selectAll('circle')
    .call(drag);

  focus.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'axis axis--x')
    .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + height + ')')
    .call(xAxis);

  focus.append('g')
    .attr('class', 'axis axis--y')
    .call(yAxis);




  function dragstarted(d) {
    d3.select(this).raise().classed('active', true);
  }

  function dragged(d) {
    // d[0] = x.invert(d3.event.x); Restringe o movimento do eixo x
    d[1] = y.invert(d3.event.y);
    d3.select(this)
      .attr('cx', x(d[0]))
      .attr('cy', y(d[1]))

    focus.select('path').attr('d', line);

  }

  function dragended(d) {
    d3.select(this).classed('active', false);
  }


</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See a solution in the snippet below:

```js
    var svg = d3.select("svg"),
        margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
        width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom;
        
    
    let points = [[0, 0], [1, 7],[2, 21],[3, 36],[4, 50],[5, 55],[6, 60],[7, 65],[8, 70],[9, 75],[10, 80],[11, 85],[12, 90],[13, 95],[14, 100],[15, 100]];
    
    var x = d3.scaleLinear()
        .rangeRound([0, width]);
    
    var y = d3.scaleLinear()
        .rangeRound([height, 0]);
    
    var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x),
        yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y);
    
    var line = d3.line()
        .x(function(d) { return x(d[0]); })
        .y(function(d) { return y(d[1]); });
        
    let drag = d3.drag()
            .on('start', dragstarted)
            .on('drag', dragged)
            .on('end', dragended);
            
    svg.append('rect')
        .attr('class', 'zoom')
        .attr('cursor', 'move')
        .attr('fill', 'none')
        .attr('pointer-events', 'all')
        .attr('width', width)
        .attr('height', height)
        .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')')
    
     var focus = svg.append("g")
                    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
    
    x.domain(d3.extent(points, function(d) { return d[0]; }));
    y.domain(d3.extent(points, function(d) { return d[1]; }));
    
    focus.append("path")
        .datum(points)
        .attr("fill", "none")
        .attr("stroke", "green")
        .attr("stroke-linejoin", "round")
        .attr("stroke-linecap", "round")
        .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
        .attr("d", line);
    
    const pointG = focus.selectAll('g.point')
        .data(points)
        .enter()
        .append('g')
        .classed('point', true)
        .attr('transform', d => `translate(${x(d[0])},${y(d[1])})`);
        
   pointG.append('circle')
        .attr('r', 5.0)
        .style('cursor', 'pointer')
        .style('fill', 'green');
    
    pointG.append('text')
            .attr("dx", ".71em")
            .attr("dy", ".35em")
            .text(function(d) { return d[1];});

    focus.selectAll('g.point')
            .call(drag);
    
    focus.append('g')
        .attr('class', 'axis axis--x')
        .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + height + ')')
        .call(xAxis);
        
    focus.append('g')
        .attr('class', 'axis axis--y')
        .call(yAxis);

        

    
    function dragstarted(d) {
        d3.select(this).raise().classed('active', true);
    }
    
    function dragged(d) {
        // d[0] = x.invert(d3.event.x); Restringe o movimento do eixo x
        d[1] = y.invert(d3.event.y);
        d3.select(this)
            .attr('transform', `translate(${x(d[0])},${y(d[1])})`)

        focus.select('path').attr('d', line);
        
    }
    
    function dragended(d) {
        d3.select(this).classed('active', false);
    }
```

```html
<svg width="500" height="500"></svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Michael

I also would like the text label to reflect the changes after the point is dragged but i've managed to implement this based on your answer which gave an insight of how these points are treated internally by D3, if anyone would like to replicate:

Just add the code below to the end of the dragged function

```
        pointG.selectAll('text').remove()

        pointG.append('text')
            .attr("dx", ".71em")
            .attr("dy", ".35em")
            .text(function(d) { return Math.round(d[1]);});
```